# Specific class in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that calculates fuel efficiency for a car. Here's the code:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, fuelEfficiency, fuelLevel):
        self.fuelEfficiency = fuelEfficiency
        self.fuelLevel = 0

    def drive(self, miles):
        gasUsed = self.fuelEfficiency * miles

        self.fuelLevel -= gasUsed

        self.fuelLevel = max(self.fuelLevel, 0)

    def get_gas_level(self):
        return self.fuelLevel

    def add_gas(self, gallons):
        self.fuelLevel += gallons

    def __str__(self):
        return ('$.2f gallons remaining.' % (self.fuelLevel))

def main():
    print("Fuel Estimator")

    fuelEfficiency = float(input('MPG: '))
    fuelLevel = float(input('Fuel: '))
    miles = float(input('Distance: '))
    gallonsRemaining = Car(fuelLevel)

    while True:
        x = input("Would you like to enter another (y/n): ")

        if x == "y":
            main()
            continue
        elif x == "n":
            break
        else:
            print("Would you like to enter another (y/n): ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here's the traceback from the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\Desktop\prog4.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Car:
  File "C:\Users\John\Desktop\prog4.py", line 47, in Car
    main()
  File "C:\Users\John\Desktop\prog4.py", line 33, in main
    gallonsRemaining = Car(fuelLevel)
NameError: name 'Car' is not defined
```

I'm still receiving a NameError stating that Car (the class) is not defined. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Is this python 3 or 2?  Also indentation is wrong.  All of the methods should be indented from the class def.  You also throw away your fuelLevel parameter.

Comment: This is python 3.

Comment: Show the complete traceback -- copy and paste it into your question

Comment: @ettanany I think that edit has introduced indentation problems as well as solving some. `def main()` and `if __name__ ...` would not typically be inside a class.

Comment: @khelwood Can you take a look at the new edit?

Comment: @ettanany Yes, but I can't approve it unilaterally.

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten the `fuelEfficiency` argument in `main`:

```
def main():
    print("Fuel Estimator")

    fuelEfficiency = float(input('MPG: '))
    fuelLevel = float(input('Fuel: '))
    miles = float(input('Distance: '))
    # gallonsRemaining = Car(fuelLevel) <- one argument is missing in __init__
    gallonsRemaining = Car(fuelEfficiency, fuelLevel)

    while True:
        x = input("Would you like to enter another (y/n): ")

        if x == "y":
            main()
            continue
        elif x == "n":
            break
        else:
            print("Would you like to enter another (y/n): ")
```

Comment: Cannot help you because after adding the missing argument, your code runs without any error on my computer.